# Getting Lat/Long for region and district of Mozambique

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, geocoding

I have a database with region and district names in Mozambique Africa.
I was wondering if it is possible to get lat/Long coordinates of those names so that I can map those locations. In a way going backward?

Comment: You're asking two different things. One question, one post. Which kind of database? Which software are you using? Without details, we can't help you. For shapefiles for Mozambique, ask in https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: What you're looking for is a geocoding service or an existing mapping of the names to coordinates (region centroids or capitals).

Comment: It may also be a gazetteer service that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You would want a batch geocoding service. A helpful one is located here: https://www.doogal.co.uk/BatchGeocoding.php

You need to:

1. Copy and paste your tabular data into the geocoder
2. Set the "Addresses are in" to "Mozambique"
3. Scroll down and click the "Text" tab, as opposed to the "Map" tab
4. Hit the blue geocode button
5. A table of address with lat long information is generated.

Note that the results of a geocoding service are only as good as the input data. Assure that your addresses have correct spelling, and that you verify the results of the geocode.